When a credible interval coincides with a confidence interval, can one interpret confidence interval as credible interval and vice versa?
Let's say I have a frequentist model with $n$ data points to derive a confidence interval for a parameter. I also have a Bayesian model with $n$ data points to derive posterior for the parameter. In finite $n$ case, the credible interval needs not agree with confidence interval. Consider $n\to\infty$, under regularity conditions with a nice prior will lead to agreement of confidence interval and credible interval.
$Q:$ In this case, if I use frequentist model and derive a confidence interval, can I interpret it as a credible interval and vice versa? Technically, frequentist interval either contains true value or not. I would guess Bayesian credible interval frequentist coverage converges at a rate of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.
$Q':$ Suppose $n$ is very large. Can I even try to interpret confidence interval as a credible interval and vice versa? There is good chance for either under or over coverage for credible interval in frequentist sense.

No, just because two numbers coincide numerically doesn't mean they allow for the same interpretation.
The fundamental principle behind Bayesian statistics is transforming a probabilistic statement about parameters based on old information (i.e., the prior) into an equivalent statement about the parameters that additionally accounts for the new information (i.e., the posterior).
$$
p(\theta|\text{old information}) \mapsto p(\theta|\text{old information, new information})
$$
That is to say, if you want a posterior probability, or some interval estimate derived from it, you need to start with a prior. That prior can be "non-informative", i.e. claiming that you have no information about $\theta$ whatsoever in the sense of $p(\theta|\text{old information}) = p(\theta|\emptyset)$, but it has to be stated.

+1 "numerical accidents"
